# Visual Studio Code test sidebar button disappeared

Tags: testing, visual-studio-code, pytest

In Visual Studio Code, the test button on the left, the one that looks like a flask, has disappeared on my machine. I tried to run the command "Test: Run All Tests", but I get a message "No tests found in this workspace. You may need to install a test provider extension". Did I just accidentally uninstall test support in VSCode? I can still run `pytest` from the command line and that works fine.

Comment: read the VSC doc about python Testing to see which settings need to be set

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OK I found out the problem myself. It seems that there is another Python executable on my Windows machine, which seems to have come with VSCode itself, at `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Python37_64\python.exe`. Somehow when I restarted VSCode, that Python executable was selected, and it didn't have `pytest` or even `unittest` or anything I don't think, so I guess VSCode saw that there was no testing capability at all and didn't bother showing the test button. It seems insane that VSCode comes with its own Python executable though, I wonder why that is.

**EDIT**
Oh oops it's Visual Studio that came with the Python executable, not VSCode, obviously as the path suggests. My bad.

Comment: It is not VSC but VS that has the Python

Answer (score 1):

This is how I solved it:

1. Press: <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd>p</kbd>
2. Type: "reload window"
3. Click on `Developer: Reload Window`

After that, you will see the **testing button** on the left panel.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. In my case, the problem was that my project was disconnected from its WSL target. In order to solve this, I had to navigate to the Remote Explorer on the left-hand side and right-click on my project to connect it to the WSL.

After doing that, all the tests showed up again.